# Searching for records with capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Our Thomas Walpole helped me a lot in this logic below. I have a problem, when the record is on the first page the button that moves to the next page in the list is disabled. How do I so if the record is on the first page it does not enter the loop that scans the screen looking for this record?

```
def cad_diametro_material_ativo
    input_codigo.send_keys('aut_Server_AL')
    input_ordem.send_keys('1')
    @gera_material_ativo =  'AUT_Server_ALUMINIO_ATIVO'+ rand(1..99).to_s
    input_descricao.send_keys(@gera_material_ativo)
    btn_inserir.click
    until page.has_css?("td", text: @gera_material_ativo, wait: 3) do
    btn_move_registros.click
    end
    find("td", text: @gera_material_ativo).click
    btn_cancelar.click
    end

    hml code

    <div id="AFRAME_14bb" onmousedown="event.preventMoving=true;" style="display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 100%;" class="tv">
       <a name="tvTDiametroMat"></a>
       <div class="tvCaption">
          <div style="display:inline-block;width:100%"><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon Enabled icon_grid" draggable="false" onclick="sendEvent(0,event,this,true,0,'','14bb','ControlMenu#','','','','','');">&nbsp;Diâmetro do Material</div>
       </div>
       <div id="TV-tvTDiametroMat">
          <div style="" class="tvContent">
             <div style="display:table;width:100%; background:inherit;">
                <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:top; background:inherit;" class="tvNavigation">
                   <div class="tvNavigation">
                      <div>1</div>
                      <div><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon icon_ro-upup" draggable="false"></div>
                      <div><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon icon_ro-up" draggable="false"></div>
                      <div><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon Enabled icon_down" draggable="false" onclick="loadPage('tvTDiametroMat','1','11',2);"></div>
                      <div><img src="r/std/static/pixel.gif" class="icon Enabled icon_downdown" draggable="false" onclick="loadPage('tvTDiametroMat','10','11',2);"></div>
                   </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
until page.has_css?("td", text: @gera_material_ativo, wait: 3) do
  btn_move_registros.click
end
```

will only click the button to go to the next page if the first page doesn't have the desired `td` element within the specified wait period. If it is clicking to go the next page even though you believe the expected `td` is on the first page then it's likely your `wait` setting isn't long enough for the first page to render. Try increasing the `wait` value